# errno value is not updated (c++)

Tags: c++

I'm new to coding (currently learning c++ & I know a little of C)...

was reading about functions in  math.h  and read about  errno...

According to the site I referred :-

> Domain error (input argument is outside the range in which the operation is mathematically defined, e.g. std::sqrt(-1), std::log(-1), or std::acos(2)). If MATH_ERRNO bit is set, EDOM is assigned to errno. If MATH_ERREXCEPT bit is set, FE_INVALID is raised.

So I tried writing a small program with that knowledge...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
  errno = 0;
  cout<<"\nWhat I get :-\n";
  cout << "log(-3) = " << log(-3) << "\n"; 
  //shouldn't it do (errno = EDOM) in the above step?
  cout << "errno = " << errno << "\n";
  cout << strerror(errno) << "\n";

  errno = EDOM;
  cout<<"\nWhat I want :-\n";
  cout << "log(-3) = " << log(-3) << "\n";
  cout << "errno = " << errno << "\n";
  cout << strerror(errno) << "\n\n";

  return(0);
}
```

And in the output I see that the errno is not getting updated to EDOM in my first block even though -3 is not in the domain of log()...

Output:-

```
What I get :-
log(-3) = nan
errno = 0
Undefined error: 0

What I want :-
log(-3) = nan
errno = 33
Numerical argument out of domain
```

I don't understand what I'm missing here...
Plz help....

I'm compiling my code on Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31) in Mac.

Comment: `std::ends` doesn't make sense with ordinary text streams. And don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#define MATH_ERRNO 1` is illegal. You should not redefine standard library symbols. MATH_ERRNO is already defined as 1 by standard.

You cannot set how implementation handles error (aside from compiler-specific switches. Read documentation for your compiler). You can only check it:

```
if (math_errhandling & MATH_ERRNO)
    std::cout << "Error reporting uses errno\n";
else 
    std::cout << "Error reporting does not use errno\n";

if (math_errhandling & MATH_ERREXCEPT)
    std::cout << "Error reporting uses floating-point exceptions\n";
else 
    std::cout << "Error reporting does not use floating-point exceptions\n";
```

For clang, relevant flags are `-fmath-errno`/`-fmath-no-errno` to use/not use `errno`.

From [discussion on reported bug](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=11858) it seems, that Mac implementation of standard library doesn't use `errno` at all. So you are out of luck if you want use it for error reporting.

Comment: Ok... I removed the #define statement... I ran the code after removing it and I'm getting the 2nd option "Error  reporting does not use errno"....

Comment: @Abhijith I have updated post. It seems that it is Mac specific behavior.

Comment: @Abhijith _I can successfully set errno to 2 though_. Well, **you** can set it to whatever you like. It is just a variable. Problem is in fact that standard library does not set it. _is this something fundamental on Mac_ I am no Mac expert, but it seems that yes, standard library bundled with Mac does not use `errno`. Potential solution would be to find library which uses it, compile it and link statically to your program, but right now, for you it would be way more trouble than it worth.

Comment: ty for your answer and  time... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find complete example (in C) of math err handling at: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/math_errhandling/
For completness example from that site:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <math.h>       /* math_errhandling */
#include <errno.h>      /* errno, EDOM */
#include <fenv.h>       /* feclearexcept, fetestexcept, FE_ALL_EXCEPT, FE_INVALID */
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS on

int main () {
  errno = 0;
  if (math_errhandling & MATH_ERREXCEPT) feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);

  printf ("Error handling: %d",math_errhandling);

  sqrt (-1);
  if (math_errhandling & MATH_ERRNO) {
    if (errno==EDOM) printf("errno set to EDOM\n");
  }
  if (math_errhandling  &MATH_ERREXCEPT) {
    if (fetestexcept(FE_INVALID)) printf("FE_INVALID raised\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a warning that "pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON is not
      supported, ignoring pragma [-Wunknown-pragmas]"... so I'm not sure if the output is what it's supposed to be... I'm getting the output of the code you posted as : " Error handling: 2 "

Comment: @Abhijith _Error handling: 2_ means that MATH_ERREXCEPT is set and MATH_ERRNO is not set.

Comment: This means that error handling mechanism employed by the functions is MATH_ERREXCEPT for what is the meaning of that please take a look at table in the provided link. P.S. I do not have clang compiler right now so I cant't check unknown pragma warning right now