# errno doesn't change after putting a negative value in sqrt()

Tags: c++, errno, cmath

With errno, I am trying to check if cmath functions produce a valid result. But even after I put a negative value in sqrt() or log(), errno stays at value 0.
Can anyone know why, and how I can make errno behave correctly?

The environment is macOS Monterey version 12.6.1, the compiler is gcc version 11.3.0 (Homebrew GCC 11.3.0_1) or Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202) (I tried the 2 compilers).
The compile command is `g++ test_errno.cpp -o test_errno -std=c++14`.

The piece of code I tried is directly copied from [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno). The following is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <clocale>
 
int main()
{
    double not_a_number = std::log(-1.0);
    std::cout << not_a_number << '\n';
    if (errno == EDOM) {
        std::cout << "log(-1) failed: " << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';
        std::setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, "de_DE.utf8");
        std::cout << "Or, in German, " << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Its result didn't print the error messages, which should be printed if errno is set correctly.

Comment: Check the value of [`math_errhandling`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/math_errhandling).

Comment: You can check the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815446/errno-value-is-not-updated-c). It seems that this issue happens on Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that on macOS, errno is not used, from [this bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11858) from @GAVD's comment.
I could check that via [math_errhandling](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/math_errhandling) value from @Pete Becker's comment.
It seems there are 2 ways of math error handling in C/C++, either with errno, or with floating-point exception, as the 2nd link above shows.
We can check which way (or both of them) the system's math library employs, via checking if macro constant `math_errhandling` is equal to `MATH_ERREXCEPT` or `MATH_ERRNO`, like the following (copied from the 2nd link):

```
    std::cout << "MATH_ERRNO is "
              << (math_errhandling & MATH_ERRNO ? "set" : "not set") << '\n'
              << "MATH_ERREXCEPT is "
              << (math_errhandling & MATH_ERREXCEPT ? "set" : "not set") << '\n';
```

And on my system, the output is

```
MATH_ERRNO is not set
MATH_ERREXCEPT is set
```

, which means the system does not use errno for reporting math errors, but use floating-point exception.
That's why errno stays at value 0 no matter what, and I should have used [`std::fetestexcept()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/fetestexcept) to check error conditions.
With floating-point exceptions, `std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);` corresponds to `errno = 0;`, and `std::fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO)` corresponds to `errno == ERANGE` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark and guess you are enabling fast-math in your build?

Without fast-math:

https://godbolt.org/z/vMo1P7Mn1

With fast-math:

https://godbolt.org/z/jEsGz7n38

The error handling within cmath tends to break things like vectorisation & constexpr *(setting external global variables, is a side effect that breaks both cases)*. As a result, you are usually better off checking for domain errors yourself...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It turned out that mac's math library doesn't use errno by default, but use floating-point exception, as my answer explains.